# Android activity to android home and again from android home to activity

Tags: android, back-stack, onbackpressed, android-homebutton

I have 3 activities in my application.

activity1 -->activity 2--activity3

if user press back button in activity3 i am navigating to home page of the mobile using below code

```
 Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
```

then my application is navigated to the home page of the mobile. if again i click on the launcher icon of the application from mobile home page then activity2 is visible. but i need to view the same activity (activity3). can any body please help me on this ?

Comment: clear the stack of previously open activities may it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the `super.onBackPressed();`  on overriding onbackpressed, on doing like this default function of closing the current activity won't occur.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

     //super.onBackPressed();  

     // put your code here,
     // in your case

     Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
     startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
     startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a static context in the 2nd activity and while returning back from the 3rd activity

you can simply add this line on your back pressed

```
SecondActivity.staticcontext.finish()
```